# Get data by month of years

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables first one

```
Oils table 
| id | fullname |amount 
| 1  | Salma    | 70  |
| 2  | Ali      | 20  |
| 3  |  adams   | 40  |
```

Second one

```
Picking_history 
| id|oil_id|first|second|third|date 
| 1 | 3    | 5  |  10 | 25| 11-2023
```

I want sql query that can get me results like this.

```
|id|fname|amount|first|Second|thid
| 1|Salem| 70  |     |      |    |
| 2|Ali  | 20  |     |      |    |
```

I'm used this sql code

```
SELECT 
    Packing_history.id,
    Oils.fullname,
    amount,      
    Packing_history.first,
    Packing_history.second,
    Packing_history.third
FROM 
    Packing_history 
INNER JOIN 
    Oils 
ON 
    Packing_history oil_id != Oils.id 
WHERE 
    Packing_history.date != '11-2023'
GROUP BY 
    Packing_history.id
```

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: `GROUP BY Packing_history.id` does nothing as that `id` column is _presumably_ the PK. Why would you want to join where the `oil_id` does not match? What is the relevance of `Packing_history.date != '11-2023'`? Why are you storing months as `11-2023` instead of `2023-11` or `202311`? Are you just looking for a simple anti-join - `SELECT * FROM Oils o LEFT JOIN Packing_history ph ON o.id = ph.oil_id AND ph.date = '11-2023' WHERE ph.id IS NULL;`?

Comment: Ok I will try it

Comment: is table 2 `picking` or `packing` (you have used both), the sample data shown cannot match the where clause `where date != '11-2023'`  Your query does **not** need  `GROUP BY` clause as there is no aggregation. See https://dbfiddle.uk/rSXh6zKv